# Passing Json Object to webmethod giving Internal server error 500

Tags: asp.net, json

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PassJavascriptObjectArraytoWebmethod() {

            var CustomerArr = [];
            var Customer = new Object();
            Customer.CustomerId = "1";
            Customer.Name = 'Rakesh';
            Customer.Address = 'Mumbai';

            CustomerArr.push(Customer);

            var Customer = new Object();
            Customer.CustomerId = "2";
            Customer.Name = 'Sandesh';
            Customer.Address = 'Banglore';

            CustomerArr.push(Customer);

            var param = JSON.stringify(CustomerArr)

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default2.aspx/AddCustomer',
                data: param,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                alert(result.d);
                }
            });


        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <span onclick="javascript:PassJavascriptObjectArraytoWebmethod();">Call Customer</span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

here is my code behid webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddCustomer(Customer[] CustomerArr)
{
   return "some result";
}
```

and here is the exception i get in console

"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 0):

you should pass object array with same name

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default2.aspx/AddCustomer',
                data: {CustomerArr:param },
                // same name
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                alert(result.d);
                }
            });
```